# Disagreement between ECJ and Javac in overload resolution with functional interfaces for primitve types

Tags: java, eclipse, overloading, overload-resolution

I have a disagreement between Eclipse ecj and Oracle Javac compiler. The following code compiles with Javac, both jdk8 (1.8.0_131) and jdk9 () pre-release, but Eclipse 4.7 with JDT 3.13.0.v20170612-0950 reports an error:

```
import java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction;
import java.util.function.ToIntFunction;

public class Test {
    static class Generic<T> {
    }

    public static <T> String map(Generic<T> o, ToIntFunction<? super T> f) {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T> Number map(Generic<T> o, ToDoubleFunction<? super T> f) {
        return null;
    }

    private static int double2int(double x) {
        return 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<Double> oEmpty = new Generic<>();

        map(oEmpty, Test::double2int);
    }
}
```

> The method map(Test.Generic, ToIntFunction) is
>   ambiguous for the type Test   Test.java   /Playground/src/sandbox line
>   25    Java Problem

I am not very familiar with the details of overload resolution of the Java language. double2int is assignable to both `ToIntFunction` and `ToDoubleFunction`, so intuitively I can see why it could be ambiguous. However, the assignment to `ToDoubleFunction` involves a conversion from the `int` result to `double`, so I would expect that `ToIntFunction` is a better match and the ambiguity is resolved.

Comment: Could be Eclipse coniguration issue? somthing about "autoboxing" to be reported as compile error? Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings -> Potential Programming Problems -> Boxing and unboxing conversions

Comment: What ecj version and javac versions are you using?

Comment: Looks like [Eclipse bug 429090](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429090)

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I've added version information. I am using the latest jdk8, and downloaded a new jdk9 pre-release. My Eclipse is 4.7.

Comment: @gmanjon Autoboxing warnings are set to Ignore in my configuration.

Comment: Which java language level and target are your eclipse configuration using?

Comment: @gmanjon Both are set to 1.8. ToDoubleFunction and ToIntFunction are java8 interfaces, so it wouldn't compile otherwise.